# How do I link to internal images in my markdown post in gatsbyjs?

Tags: gatsby

**Goal:**
I'm trying to *link* to an image I have located in my images folder from a markdown post:

```
This is supposed to be a [link](../images/image.png) to my image.
```

When clicking the link, I'm expecting it to lead to a page containing the image only.

**Problem:**
I'm trying to use a relative path as this is also how I would give the path if I was actually displaying the image (`![alt text](../images/image.png)`).

However, gatsbyjs does not seem to recognise the relative path as image source and tries to go to the page `domain/images/image.png`, which is not the url gatsbyjs reserves for the image (it will be a randomly generated one).

**Question:** Is there an easy way of linking to my image?

Comment: https://www.gatsbyjs.com/plugins/gatsby-plugin-relative-paths/ ?

Comment: If I understand correctly, I will need to store my assets in the generated public folder to use this plugin? Not sure if that's a pretty solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Complete Re-edit of answer:

```
/static
 /images
  imagefile
```

the above will create an images folder in your `/public` directory.

You can then source this in your markdown each time as `[link](/images/imageFile.extension)`. This is a little bit of a 'hands on' approach and would require manually loading in your images to static.

### The Gatsby way:

Place this inside your `gatsby-node`

```js
import path from 'path';
import fsExtra from 'fs-extra';

export const onCreateNode = async ({
  node, actions
}) => {
  const sourceNorm = path.normalize(`${__dirname}/src/images`);
  const destination = `/images`;

  if (node.internal.type === 'File') {
    const dir = path.normalize(node.dir);

    if (dir.includes(sourceNorm)) {
      const relativeToDestination = dir.replace(sourceNorm, '');
      const newPath = path.join(
        process.cwd(),
        'public',
        destination,
        relativeToDestination,
        node.base
      );

      fsExtra.copy(node.absolutePath, newPath, err => {
        if (err) {
          console.log('Error copying file: ', err)
        }
      })
    }
  }
}
```

The above will take all of your images that are specified in `/src/images` and create nodes for them in the `public` folder during build/develop to the destination at `/images/`.

You should then be able to link to your images with `/images/image.extension`

Comment: Thank you for looking into this, this works without any issues! Minor edit to answer: image file path at the end should be `/images/imageFile.extension`

Comment: Yeah .extension just means like [jpg/png]

Comment: Glad its all working well for you :)